# Stop moment from formatting hours

Tags: javascript, momentjs

'm using moment to format some of my times in my app. This is working wonderfully, however I have one spot where I am counting how many hours instead of converting it to a regular time format.

The time that I have to work with looks something like this. `0:00:02 AM`

and my formatting like of looks like this. I'm trying to strip out the am pm since it is not needed here

```
moment('0:00:02 AM', 'hh:mm:ss').format('hh:mm:ss')
```

this is turning it to 12:00:02, but I need it to stay at 00:00:02. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've added a working example of my answer to your question. I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

[You need to use `HH` instead of `hh`.](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

> H or HH    |   0..23   |   24 hour time

An example has been included below:

```js
var thing = moment('0:00:02 AM', 'hh:mm:ss').format('HH:mm:ss');
document.write(thing);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried that, it still returns the same 12:00:02

Comment: `moment('0:00:02 AM', 'hh:mm:ss').format('HH:mm:ss');` returns `"00:00:02"` (http://jsbin.com/qumirifavi/edit?html,css,js,console)

Comment: @zazvorniki did this every get sorted? My jsbin shows the code working and showing the desired output.